# How to understand myFieldInfo.GetValue(null) when using Reflection?

Tags: c#

Here are my code about reflection:

```
class Program
{
    private static int a = 100;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a=" + a);

        Type t = typeof(Program);
        FieldInfo myFieldInfo = t.GetField("a",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Static);
        if (myFieldInfo!=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The current value of a is "+myFieldInfo.GetValue(null)+", please enter a new value:");
            string newValue = Console.ReadLine();
            int newInt;
            if (int.TryParse(newValue,out newInt))
            {
                myFieldInfo.SetValue(null, newInt);
                Console.WriteLine("a=" + a);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It can work! But I really don't understand the meaning of the `null` in the `myFieldInfo.GetValue(null)`and the `myFieldInfo.SetValue(null, newInt);`, and I read the MSDN about the [FieldInfo.GetValue Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), I found that the `Object`mean "The object whose field value will be returned. ". So It really confused me why the parameter should be `null`?

Comment: Because it's a static field, there's no instance to pass. Scroll down and read the Remarks: _"If the field is static, obj is ignored"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you will put in there the instance you want to get the field value from. Since in your code the field is static, it is not bound to an instance. Hence, the instance parameter can (and should) be null.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is static, From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the field is static, obj is ignored. For non-static fields, obj should be an instance of a class that inherits or declares the field